# Limit in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with cosine function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> I have to find the limit of the following expression: 
>   $$\lim_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (0,0,0)} \frac{2x^2y\cos{z}}{x^2+y^2}$$

I made equal $x=y=z$ and got $\lim \to 0$. Then I did, $x^2 = y $ which led me to $\lim \to 2$. I would want to know if my procedure was correct and if there is a trick to determine the equivalences between the variables.

Edit: Thanks to @gt6989b for his edits and also I noticed that I was wrong in  if $x^2 = y $ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim \to 2$

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalences between the variables ?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a mistake with your algebra, because

$$
\left|\frac{2x^2y\cos(z)}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|=  2\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}|y||\cos(z)|\le 2|y|
$$
which shows that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I get what you did by doing $|f(x,y,z)-L|$ but I can't get why it is sufficient that if $|f(x,y,z)-L| ≤ 2|y|$ then $0$ is the limit. I understand the fraction is less than or equal to 1 and $\cos{z} ≤ 1$. Is $2|y|$  the epsilon and why does that works?

Comment: @RolandoGonzález Given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. We always have that $\|(x,y,z)\|\le |y|$. So, if $\|(x,y,z)\|<\delta$, we can deduce that $|f(x,y,z)-L|\le 2|y|\le 2\delta<\varepsilon$.